# Django forms.form header field

Tags: django

I want to have a field type in forms.form that just takes in the text of a header to be displayed so the HTML would be something like:

> This is header text for this section
>
> Question
>
> Question
>
> Question
>
> Another header
>
> Question
>
> Question

The idea is I'm declaring all the questions in the form on the fly using a model just for question pages, I need a header for some sections just to say what the sections are about. The inserting the questions on the fly is all working well so far it's just I need the last bit of display code to make it functional for what I need.

To give more information, this is my approach:

1. the admin creating the form creates questions in the admin interface
2. then adds the questions to a question form
3. when a user goes to the question page it renders the page with the questions using forms.form

The questions are declared using:

> self.fields['id'] = forms.CharField(
>                       max_length=100,
>                       label=text, required=q.question.required)

What I want is to replace the above line with something like HeaderField which just has header text in a H1/2/3/4...etc container.

So the ideal syntax I want is

> self.fields['id'] = forms.HeaderField(label=text, type=1)

Where type 1 is H1, 2 would be H2...etc

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out a solution on the spot using another answer. The solution was just mark the label as safe for HTML, then I can add HTML in directly and style it afterwards.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

self.fields['id'.format(q.question.id)] = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.Textarea,
                max_length=1000,
                label=mark_safe(text), required=q.question.required)
```

After I do that I can add things like H1 or BR and style it directly. It's a little bit clunky but at least it works with the code that I already had.